# Python Regex extract variables

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I try to extract 3 variables from a string with Python3 regex.

The String:

```
document.getElementById('dlbutton').href = "/d/05UJmMTa/" + (213059 % 51245 + 213059 % 913) + "/Cool%20Customer%20-%20In%20Your%20Face%20%28Original%20Mix%29.mp3";
```

I would like extract:

- `/d/05UJmMTa/`
- `213059 % 51245 + 213059 % 913`
- `/Cool%20Customer%20-%20In%20Your%20Face%20%28Original%20Mix%29.mp3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
inp = "document.getElementById('dlbutton').href = \"/d/05UJmMTa/\" + (213059 % 51245 + 213059 % 913) + \"/Cool%20Customer%20-%20In%20Your%20Face%20%28Original%20Mix%29.mp3\";"
parts = re.findall(r'\.href\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*\+\s*\((.*?)\)\s*\+\s*"(.*?)"', inp)
print(parts[0])
```

This prints:

```
['/d/05UJmMTa/',
 '213059 % 51245 + 213059 % 913',
 '/Cool%20Customer%20-%20In%20Your%20Face%20%28Original%20Mix%29.mp3']
```